# Error with time.sleep

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am new to Python3 and I have some problems. I've created a program like this:

`x = input("Type a number: ")
time.sleep(x)`

Every time I use this I get an error. I don't know what I am doing wrong, could someone help me?

Comment: That's what I get: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console input is of type `str` by default:

Type cast it to `int`.

```
x = int(input("Type a number: "))
time.sleep(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me.